# How to access a particular View inside a Fragment from the parent Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `ProgessBar` inside my `Fragment`, and I need the `Fragment`'s parent `Activity` to access the `ProgressBar`.

Right now, I have created a getProgressBar() method inside the `Fragment` that returns a reference to it.  Then inside the parent `Activity` I do this:

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");  

ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) fragment.getProgressBar();
```

Is there a better, widely accepted way to do this?

Comment: That way seems to be an acceptable one. But make sure that fragment is not null.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It works, but for some reason it just feels strange to return a reference to a View like that.  I thought there might be some more standardized way to do it.

Comment: If it has an id, why not use findViewById(id)?

Comment: @AllenG Wouldn't that mean I would need to inflate the layout again inside my Activity?

Comment: @JDJ No, findViewById(id) just returns a View object. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Once the Fragment has loaded, it's Views are attached to the Activity's View hierarchy, and `findViewById()` will then work for those Views in the Fragment's layout.

Comment: @JDJ findViewById searches the entire view hierarchy for the Activity (or whatever item you're running it on), including child fragments. As long as the fragment is attached to the Activity, findViewById will find it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I will use findViewById().  If you want to create an answer for this I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findViewById()` on the `Activity` as long as the object has an id. It will search the `Activity`'s entire view hierarchy, including attached child fragments, and is cleaner/easier to understand.